# Simple HTML website not rendering as expected in Firefox, Safari and IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I have created a simple website using HTML and CSS.

Primarily developed using Chrome, I now see that the site does not render as expected on Fx, Safari or IE. There are layout issues, i.e. tags/buttons appear to be misplaced.

Are there any declarations to be made for the site to be compliant as per Chrome?

```css
#wrapper {
  /*background-color: #ffff99;*/
  width: 1150px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 26.4px;
}
header {
  background-color: #a6dd88;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#company {
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
  bottom: 115px;
  font-size: 35pt;
  color: #003300;
}
#iaw {
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
  bottom: 140px;
  color: #2db300;
  font-weight: 200;
}
#p1 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 170px;
  right: 340px;
  color: #005e00;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
}
#p2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 255px;
  right: 80px;
  color: #005e00;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
}
#comms {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 455px;
  right: 45px;
}
nav {
  width: 510px;
  position: relative;
  left: 650px;
  bottom: 335px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*background-color: blue;*/
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#content {
  background-color: #79bf56;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
}
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14.5px;
  /*margin: 4px 50px 2px 50px;* <Button space inbetween>*/
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}
.button1:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
footer {
  background-color: #a6dd88;
  position: relative;
}
#footer {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
table,
td,
th {
  /*border: 1px solid #003300;*/
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 260px;
  margin-bottom: -250px;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
}
#ov {
  color: #004d00;
}
#ovw {
  font-weight: 100;
}
#clsp {
  text-align: center;
  color: #063b03;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}
#c1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #e6e600;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}
#c2 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e6e600;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-style: italic;
}
#com {
  text-align: center;
  color: #063b03;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}
#wwat {
  text-align: center;
  color: #063b03;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}
#wwa {
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.wwa {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 145px;
}
ul.org {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: square;
  list-style-position: inside;
  font-size: 15pt;
  list-style-position: all;
  font-style: italic;
}
table#rtb {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 325px;
  left: 10px;
  border: none;
}
#rttb {
  font-style: bold;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
}
table#test1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 270px;
  border: 1px solid #003300;
  border-collapse:
}
#oc {
  text-align: center;
  color: #063b03;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
#cd {
  text-align: center;
  color: #006600;
}
#ca {
  text-align: center;
  color: #006600;
  position: relative;
  left: 145px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Who We Are</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chambers.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <img id="logo" src="http://www.carlogos.org/uploads/car-logos/Jaguar-logo-6.jpg" alt="Company" height="100px" width="130px" />
      <a href="Index.html"><h1 id="company">This Text appears correctly</h1></a>
      <h6 id="iaw"><em>This Text appears correctly</em></h6>
      <h6 id="p1">This Text appears correctly<br> This Text appears correctly</h6>
      <h6 id="p2">This Text appears correctlappears correctly<br> 
      appears correctly</h6>
      <h5 id="comms">This Text appears correctly<br>This Text appears correctly<br>E: This Text appears correctly</h5>
      <nav>
        <a href="index.html">
          <button class="button button1">Home</button>
        </a>
        <a href="WhoWeAre.html">
          <button class="button button1">Who We Are</button>
        </a>
        <a href="WhyUs.html">
          <button class="button button1">Why Us?</button>
        </a>
        <a href="Testimonials.html">
          <button class="button button1">Testimonials</button>
        </a>
        <a href="ContactUs.html">
          <button class="button button1">Contact Us</button>
        </a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
      <p id="wwat">This Text appears correctly</p>
      <table id="rtb">
        <tr>
          <td>
            This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure. This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in
            FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that
            was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.
            <br>
            <br>This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure. This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly
            in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there
            that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.
            <br>
            <br>This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure. This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly
            in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there
            that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.
            <br>
            <br>This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure. This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly
            in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there
            that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.
            <br>
            <br>This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure. This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly
            in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there
            that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.
            <br>
            <br>This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure. This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly
            in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there
            that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.
            <br>
            <br>
            <p id="wwat">xxxxxxxxx</p>
            This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure. This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in
            FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.This is text there that
            was entered but appears incorrectly in FireFox and Internet Adventure.
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <footer>
        <ul>
          </br>
          <li id="li1"><b><em>This Text appears correctly</em></b>
          </li>
          <li id="liadd">This Text appears correctlyThis Text appears correctly</li>
          <li id="li2"><b>This Text appears correctly<b></li>
       <li id="li3"><em>This Text appears correctly</em></li>
       </br>
      </ul>
     </footer>
     </div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your HTML has several errors. Use a validator. Also check the CSS errors in the console (e.g. there’s no `font-style: bold;`). Some properties directly override others like `list-style-position` in `ul.org` (which also uses the invalid `all` value). Also what is Internet Adventure?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for clearing up my post. I will take a look via console and validator. Quick run, was surprised to see 4 errors and notably the table error. Got some homework to do, hopefully will not come back but to upvote and mark as answer! Think of Internet Adventure like Christopher Columbus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't good, lots of tidying you can do, but to fix the error try editing these classes:

```
table {
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  /* bottom: 260px; < remove this */
  /* margin-bottom: -250px; < remove this */
}
```

and

```
table#rtb {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  /* bottom: 325px; < remove this  */
  left: 10px;
  border: none;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwXgWr

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Removing these lines resulted in a much better table layout in Firefox but in Chrome, there seems to be a chunk of space I cannot figure out where, that pushes the table half way down the page.

Comment: On #comms change position to 'absolute', remove bottom and change it to "top: -20px;". It's very hacky though, the code is a bit of a mess tbh.